# Bootsfaces, ajax, jsf and beans

Tags: ajax, jsf, bootsfaces

I am working on a school project where I have a front-end-project and a back-end-project. 
In my front-end-project I am using Bootsfaces version 1.2.0 and jsf. Back-end I have a webservice and a postgres database.

I am trying to add objects (in this case cars) through a form in my front-end-project through my webservice and also delete these objects. My problem is that it only works sometimes (usually just one time). I have tried a lot of different solutions and also browsed google for a few days..

Here is some code (simplified).

Frontend html-page:

```
            <b:dataTable value="#{leasingCarBean.carList}" var="car"
                id="carsTable">
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.licensenumber}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.brand}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.model}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.color}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.year}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn label="Delete">
                    <b:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="ajax:leasingCarBean.deleteCar(car.licensenumber)" update="carsTable"/>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
            </b:dataTable>


            <b:button size="lg" look="info" value="New car" 
                onclick="$('.modalPseudoClass').modal();ajax:leasingCarBean.createNewCar()"
                />

            <b:modal id="amodal" title="New car" styleClass="modalPseudoClass">
                <h:form>
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Licensenumber"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.licensenumber}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Brand"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.brand}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Model"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.model}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Color"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.color}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Year"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.year}" />
                </h:form>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <b:button value="Close" dismiss="modal" />
                    <b:commandButton value="Add" look="primary" dismiss="modal"
                        onclick="ajax:leasingCarBean.postNewCar()" update="carsTable" />
                </f:facet>
            </b:modal>
```

Backingbean frontend

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LeasingCarBean implements Serializable{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   private Cardto newCar;
   private Customerdto newCustomer;

   private WebTarget leasingCarTarget =  ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/leasingcarbackend/leasingcar");

   public LeasingCarBean() {}

   @PostConstruct
   public void init() {
       newCar = new Cardto();
       newCustomer = new Customerdto();
   }

   public List<Cardto> getCarList() {
       return leasingCarTarget.path("/carList").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<Cardto>>() {});
   }

   public void deleteCar(String licensenumber) {
    leasingCarTarget.path("/deleteCar/{licensenumber}").resolveTemplate("licensenumber", licensenumber).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).delete();
   }

   public void postNewCar() {
    leasingCarTarget.path("/newCar").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(newCar));
       newCar = null;
   }

   public void createNewCar() {
       newCar = new Cardto();
   }

   public Cardto getNewCar() {
       return newCar;
   }
}
```

Some of my errors:

1. When I have added a car, and then click a delete button (on any car in the datatable) it evaluates the wrong EL-expression, leasingCarBean.newCar.licensenumber instead of leasingCarBean.deleteCar(car.licensenumber).
2. When I press the "New car"-button it invokes the postNewCar-method before I have pressed the "Add"-button, which means I get null-errors because I haven't filled in the form.
3. Sometimes when i try to add a new car I get this error even though I have filled in the form:

   ```
   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: /admin/allCars.xhtml @100,57     
   value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.licensenumber}": Target Unreachable, 'null' returned null
   ```

Any tips on how to do this?
I will be grateful for any help :)

Cheers!

Comment: when you show the modal you might need to update the form to load in the newCar? eg `<h:form id="modalForm">` then in the `createNewCar` method you could refresh the form like `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getPartialViewContext().getRenderIds().add("modalForm");`

Comment: Thank you for your tip, but unfortunately it did not work. My solution below was the answer to this question. Thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I solved my problem and I wanted to post it here if someone else is interested in the solution.

My html-page:

```
   //My datatable stays the same

            <b:dataTable value="#{leasingCarBean.carList}" var="car"
                id="carsTable">
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.licensenumber}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.brand}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.model}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.color}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn value="#{car.year}" />
                <b:dataTableColumn label="Delete">
                    <b:commandButton value="Delete" onclick="ajax:leasingCarBean.deleteCar(car.licensenumber)" 
                    oncomplete="javascript:location.reload();"/>
                </b:dataTableColumn>
            </b:dataTable>


            <b:button size="lg" look="info" value="New car" 
                onclick="$('.modalPseudoClass').modal()" /> 
                //Took away createNewCar()

            <b:modal id="amodal" title="New car" styleClass="modalPseudoClass">
                <h:form>
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Licensenumber"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.licensenumber}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Brand"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.brand}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Model"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.model}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Color"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.color}" />
                    <b:inputText placeholder="Year"
                        value="#{leasingCarBean.newCar.year}" />
                </h:form>
                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <b:button value="Close" dismiss="modal" />
                    <b:commandButton value="Add" look="primary"
                        onclick="$('.modalPseudoClass').modal('hide');ajax:leasingCarBean.postNewCar()" 
                       //Dismiss modal do not work for commandButton
                        update="carsTable" />
                </f:facet>
            </b:modal>
```

Backing bean frontend:

```
@Named
@ViewScoped
public class LeasingCarBean implements Serializable{
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

private Cardto newCar;
private Customerdto newCustomer;

private WebTarget leasingCarTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target("http://localhost:8080/leasingcarbackend/leasingcar");

public LeasingCarBean() {}

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    newCar = new Cardto();
    newCustomer = new Customerdto();
}

public List<Cardto> getCarList() {
    return leasingCarTarget.path("/carList").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(new GenericType<List<Cardto>>() {});
}

public void deleteCar(String licensenumber) {
    leasingCarTarget.path("/deleteCar/{licensenumber}").resolveTemplate("licensenumber", licensenumber).request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).delete();
}

public void postNewCar() {
    leasingCarTarget.path("/newCar").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(Entity.json(newCar));
    newCar = new Cardto(); //Instead of = null
}

//This method is not needed anymore
public void createNewCar() {
    newCar = new Cardto();
}

public Cardto getNewCar() {
    return newCar;
}
```

Hopefully this will help someone in the future :)

Comment: Glad to hear you've solved the bug! However, I'm still puzzled what the bug is. I read your question this morning and found it a weird problem. I suspect the problem is that the modal dialog is rendered at the same as the datatable. That's too early because `newCar` is null. So it's a good idea to add `rendered="null != newCar"` to the form inside the modal, and to update it with an AJAX request when the modal is opened (after setting `newCar=new Cardto()`).

Comment: I can only guess, but I think BootsFaces gets confused by the `NullPointerException`. That might explain why wrong EL expressions are executed. Still, it's weird, and I don't understand what's going on.

Comment: BTW, when you click the "new car" button a second time, you probably see the old data. Adding the AJAX update solves that issue.

Comment: Hi Stephan, I dont think I follow you. In what way do you mean I should update the form with AJAX? And yes, you are right about my old data, it is still there when i push the new car button a second time (if I don't reload the page of course).

Comment: The entire JSF page is rendered at load time. This includes the modal dialog. Thing is, the modal is invisible, so it shouldn't be rendered. But JSF doesn't know that the modal is hidden by CSS, so the HTML code is rendered nonetheless. Now for the catch: when you hit the "new car" button, you simply make the modal visible. But it still contains the original data. What you want to achieve, is, that the modal shows the (empty) new car. That's why the update is needed. The modal should be updated after selecting the row, but before making it visible.

Comment: Yes I understood that part, but what I don't understand is how I can update the form with AJAX on my html-page. I googled it but I could not find how.